Canvas Module Fails to Handle JPEG Files in Node.js
I'm trying to use .jpeg file on canvas but it keeps get error of
"Error: node-canvas was built without JPEG support"
I already installed GTK and libjpeg (I added the paths of both to the system variables.)
I reinstalled npm but I keep getting errors
The error message:
Error: node-canvas was built without JPEG support
at setSource (C:\Users\tikhi\node_modules\canvas\lib\image.js:94:13)
at Image.set (C:\Users\tikhi\node_modules\canvas\lib\image.js:65:9)
at C:\Users\tikhi\node_modules\canvas\index.js:34:15
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Object.loadImage (C:\Users\tikhi\node_modules\canvas\index.js:23:10)
at createHeaderImage (C:\Users\tikhi\Desktop\discord-header-bot\bot.js:48:37)
at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\tikhi\Desktop\discord-header-bot\bot.js:27:40)
at Client.emit (node:events:518:28)
at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\tikhi\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:32:14)
at module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\tikhi\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)

